# Converting a matrix to polar coordinates (python)

Tags: matrices, polar-coordinates, change-of-basis, python

Given an $m\times n$ matrix how would you convert it to polar coordinates?

My understanding is that each element $i,j$ in the matrix relates to a Cartesian point $(x,y)$. The data at $i,j$ is the data to be plotted at $(x,y)$ when the matrix is plotted.

I would like to convert to polar coordinates so that each element $i',j'$ in the resulting matrix relates to a Polar point $(\rho, \theta)$ defined to be the radial distance from the origin and the degree from the positive $x$-axis. The data at $i,j$ would be the data to be plotted at $(\rho, \theta)$ in the properly converted matrix.

Converting the coordinates is easy using the standard method:
$$\rho = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$, $$\theta = \arctan\frac{x}{y}$$

How do I correlate the right data from the matrix to these points?

Can I flatten the matrix and interpolate the data within and then match that with the appropriate rho and theta?

How do I determine what to correlate with a given $\rho$ and $\theta$?

I plan to implement this in python so any specific advice is appreciated but at the moment my understanding of the logic is incomplete and that is my issue.
If anything is incorrect or more info is needed please let me know and I'll fix my post. Thank you!

Comment: It's uncommon to "plot" matrices because they exist on high-dimensional vector space ($\dim(M)=mn$). Could you clarify what you mean by the matrix containing cartesian points?

Comment: I'm plotting them in python with matplotlib.pyplot.imshow. I believe it plots as I described but I could be mistaken. The matrix represents a PDE at a certain point in time.

Comment: You probably need to figure out what your input "array shape" is, and clarify how $i,j$ maps to $(x,y)$. I suspect you're not using matrices at all just arrays...

Comment: The structure of the individual inputs is (64, 64) which is handled as a 2d array in the way matrices are in python. I clarify individual inputs because I initially have an array of these (64, 64) matrices but iterating through them is trivial.

Comment: So if you have a 2D array of numbers and they get plotted to pixels in a pixel-grid of the same dimensions, we're dealing with a discrete 2D function $f(x,y)$ that you want to turn into $g(\rho,\theta)$ if I'm not mistaken. This will naturally mean not all $(\rho,\theta)$ are in the domain of $g$ (since $f$ was discrete). If you want all $(\rho,\theta)$ to be in the domain of $g$ you have to [extend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Restriction_and_extension) the function by [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation).

Comment: You're right! I was only thinking of 1D interpolation. So if I use scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator I will receive a function capable of returning the interpolated result for any (,), lets call this function interp. Then how do I convert to (,) ?  Can I take each (,), calculate the corresponding (,) and then store the result of interp(,)) in the (,) location in a new matrix and then plot that?

Comment: The best way is probably to say $(x,y)=(x(\rho,\theta),y(\rho,\theta))$ and given input $(\rho,\theta)$ you can sample (interpolate) your $(x,y)$-grid because I think it would be unwise to restructure the data say into columns of $\theta$ and rows of $\rho$. So simply find $(x(\rho,\theta),y(\rho,\theta))$ and interpolate for $f(x,y)$

Comment: My goal to be able to plot the polar data with implot to compare to the implot of the input matrix. What do you mean by (,) and (,)? Each (,) correspond to a (,) so what is being changed in saying (,)=((,),(,))? My thought is that converting (1,1) to polar gives the point (1.414, 0.785) which is useless for the discrete input matrix but can be interpolated from the original results by interp(1.414, 0.785). This would be the data that corresponds to the (1,1) location originally and should be plotted as such.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is it's more reliable (consistent) to interpolate on your original $(x,y)$ data ($f$) than on the $(\rho,\theta)$ data ($g$). Are you saying implot will produce for you a *polar plot*? What else is there to solve here?